# Summing a variable range excluding certain values VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and am trying to create a report template for work. I also want to see how this would be coded for my own personal understanding instead of using a formula.

Put simply I have a variable set of values in `column A` and dates in `column B`. `Column D` is a variable range of dates (user input. I would like to have this as an array within my code.)

I would like to sum `column A` while excluding the dates specified in `column D`, and have this sum output into cell `G1`. I have attached a picture below.

Thanks in advance!

[Picture of the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXlpM.png)

Comment: How have you **tried** to code it?  Did it work?  If not, show what you tried and we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this code, this is self explanatory.

```
Sub sumVariables()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, sum As Long, match As Boolean
sum = 0
match = False
For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i, 2) = Cells(j, 4) Then
            match = True
        End If
    Next j
    If match = False Then
        sum = sum + Cells(i, 1)
    End If
    match = False
Next i
Cells(1, 7) = sum
End Sub
```

This code would work for n number of rows in your sheet and give the total in `G1`. Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Hey Gowtham, 
This worked perfectly. Thanks for your help!